# jquery ui resizable weird white patch in the middle of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

i'm playing around with jquery ui resizable with the default example from jquery ui's site and i noticed a white patch in the middle of my div:

the white patch is only visible if i put a background color to my div such as:

```
background-color: cyan;
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9aQUz/

anyone knows what's going on?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yep they're right http://jsfiddle.net/9aQUz/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample,  you've given the div the "ui-widget-content" class.

In jqueryui,  this class has the following background defination.

```
background: #ffffff/*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50%/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/;
```

In the base theme, this is just a white image.

You shouldn't need to assign jquery classes to elements.  Whenever you call the function, it'll happen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from jQuery's theme. It inserts a 40x100 image (http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) as the background for the class `.ui-widget-content`. It's done automatically when you use the resizable widget.

If it really bugs you you can override it by adding `background-image: none;` to your rule.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9aQUz/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly if you have the `css` there instead of pulling it in:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/9aQUz/3/)